# Using if/else statement with unplaced labels in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, maplex, if-else

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1.

I am planning on using maplex engine for labeling of tens of thousands of polygons. I would like to keep from transferring to annotation until absolutely necessary.

I have done some research and I do not think it is possible, but maybe someone else has had success.

I am trying to make a labeling expression with unplaced labels that would achieve the goal:

- Label using "Column1" & "Column2"
- But if label is unplaced then label with "Column3"

Is it possible to use unplaced labels in an expression when labeling?

Comment: Did you look into abbreviation dictionaries? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/abbreviate-and-truncate-labels.htm

Comment: Hmm, I did not, but that seems like it maybe would have done the trick! I am no longer on that project, but I will keep it in mind if I run into the problem again.